# C# Regex finds only one match

Tags: c#, regex

I have a regex pattern which extract url and link text to turns custom tag to  tag.
When i try my pattern on online checker it find 4 matceh, but when i run my code c# finds only one match.

```
 Regex rgx = new Regex(@"(\[)+(http:\/\/www\.|https:\/\/www\.|http:\/\/|https:\/\/)?[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)( )(.)+(\])");
```

The Entry is like

```
 [http://facebook.com/ LinkText]

[http://youtube.com/ LinkText]

[http://instagram.com/ LinkText]

[https://stackoverflow.com/users/1131979/cagri-d-kaynar LinkText]
```

My Code

```
  Regex rgx =
 new Regex(@"(\[)+(http:\/\/www\.|https:\/\/www\.|http:\/\/|https:\/\/)?[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)( )(.)+(\])");
                    foreach (Match match in rgx.Matches(entry))
                    {

                        var matchv = match.Value;
                       /*extract url and Link text from match value*/
                        var bknz =
                            String.Format("<a href=\"{0}\" target=\"_blank\">{1}</a>", cc[0], cc[1]);
                        entry = rgx.Replace(entry, bknz);
                    }
```

Whats wron with my code? Did i missa flag or ste?

Comment: The easiest way to fix your regex is to use one of the many online testers. This one is for C# http://regexstorm.net/tester

Comment: Your whole `foreach` is not necessary, replace it with `entry = rgx.Replace(entry, "<a href=\"$&\" target=\"_blank\">$1</a>");` - if `cc[0]` is the whole match and `cc[1]` is the Group 1 value. You may need to re-group the pattern to use this simpler syntax.

Comment: By the way, parsing urls is notoriously difficult, https://mathiasbynens.be/demo/url-regex there is the old adage: you have a problem so you use a regex, now you have two problems :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replace the \r\n to `<br />` before Regex pattern match and it causes the getting one match.
I do the replacement after checking regex matches. Now it's working well